# Docker Image Inspection JSON Interpretation

Tags: docker

If I run the following command against an image:

```
docker image inspect 05147492a70c
```

It give me back a JSON! In that JSON there is a field that says parent:

```
"Parent": "sha256:fc912765166f776311425fd4a30f26a7ceae1026a47c0f962c4383480824d25e",
```

What is this? What information is this? What can I infer from this information? How to identify what this sha256 belong to?

Comment: Maybe first spend some time [reading the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/).

Comment: Why did you downvote! There was no information regarding parent in the link you posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent of an image points to the next layer up in the docker image storage. If you run a `docker history` command, you'll see all of these layers in order:

```
$ docker inspect jenkins-blueocean -f '{{ .Parent }}'
sha256:1bf44d62c29e5b9f56351183c0ddc104d55045d52b1d4bb97ba8ca3b7cda58e9

$ docker history jenkins-blueocean
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
1f42c255e4f9        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoin...   0B                  
1bf44d62c29e        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:07c1588e618423...   561B                
c3f1305fcdaf        6 days ago          |2 COMPOSE_VER=1.14.0 GOSU_VERSION=1.10 /b...   89.2MB              
...
```

Note that if you pulled the image from a remote registry, rather than building locally, the child images may not exist locally and you'll see "<missing>" in that history. You still have the resulting image layers, just no image build cache of all the intermediate steps.